# Android Default Theme Doesn't match Android Training

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest, android-styles

When I started my new Android app, it asked what versions I wanted the app to support.  As I recall, I selected version 8 as my minimum.  Easy enough, but when looking into the Android Training documentation for some layout information, it pointed out that the manifest file should contain something like the following to have the Action Bar function correctly:

```
<manifest ... >
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

By default, there was no  line in my manifest file

The training files are a little older, and I'm using Android Studio 1.0.1.  Could it be stored elsewhere?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, for an Android Studio project, are usually set in the `build.gradle` file in the `app` module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.empublite"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Ah, there it is!  Knew it had to be something simple like that.  Is there a recommended min version for general use apps (and to make designing easier)?

Comment: @EdwardBagby: I would go with `minSdkVersion` of 15, as that covers [approximately 90% of devices at the moment](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), unless you have a strong business reason to do otherwise. Usually, I would set the `targetSdkVersion` to be the highest API level at the time I started the project (e.g., 21 now), unless I had a strong reason to do otherwise.